# Polymer, Dart, Chrome App, CSP and debugging

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-polymer

Similar questions have been around for a while, maybe someone knows the answer for today's stack. Ideally preserving debuggability...

I have a Dart app which implements the GUI in Polymer/Dart and the back end in Chrome/Dart. Both parts work well (many thanks) now I am trying to tie them together and debug any problems. The unified app hits a wave of CSP errors so I have put together a tiny test case. There's a spread of Dart/Polymer/CSP advice on the net but it changes as things evolve and it's very difficult to see the current best practice. Here is the test case:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Case",
  "version": "0.3",

  "icons": {"128": "dart_icon.png"},

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "app": {
      "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"]
          }
      },

  "permissions":  [ "usb"
                  , { "usbDevices": [ {"vendorId": 1027, "productId": 24597} ] }
                  , { "fileSystem": [ "write", "retainEntries", "directory" ] }
                  ]

}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create('testwrap.html', {
        'id': '_myMainWindow',
        'bounds': {'width': 800, 'height': 500 }
        });
});
```

**testwrap.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PolyChrome</title>    
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing...</h1>    
    <p>in the test directory...</p>

    <div id='container_id'>
      <p id='text_id'>The log is here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='div2'>
      <click-counter></click-counter>
    </div>

    <script type='application/dart' src='testwrap.dart'></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

**testwrap.dart**

```
import  'dart:html';
import  'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
export  'package:polymer/init.dart';

//----------------------------------------
@whenPolymerReady
void mainStartup() {
  querySelector("#text_id").text = 'Running';
  }
```

The click-counter element is the standard code from the Dart/Polymer page.

The yaml includes a $dart2js that maybe isn't used (?) or maybe having two csp:true lines is incorrect?

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: polyChrome

description: Chrome App with Polymer

dependencies:
  chrome: ^0.7.0-dev1
  code_transformers: any
  core_elements: any
  paper_elements: any
  polymer: any

transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/testwrap.html
    csp: 'true'    
- $dart2js:
    csp: 'true'
    checked: 'true'
```

The CSP error messages (all the same):

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy 
directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') 
is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' 
was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Confusingly the test app seems to work OK despite the error messages, but a larger test freezes while booting - can't ignore the messages.

The larger test gives an error message from

```
Zone zone = await initPolymer();
```

The message is the somewhat opaque (my_clock is a test polymer component that works 100% as a web app):

```
Breaking on exception: Unsupported operation: Unsupported uri scheme chrome-extension for library LibraryMirror on 'my_clock'.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the two csp lines are correct and necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't even a partial answer, but it may be helpful to others...

The csp lines have a common typo. Don't write:

```
csp: 'true'
```

This is correct (the same fix applies to checked: true) :

```
csp: true
```

And remove this line from the manifest:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
```

The search continues :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example with polymer dart

https://github.com/dart-gde/dart-chrome-app-samples/tree/master/chrome-app-with-polymer-dart

**EDIT:** you need in your pubspec.yaml to have these

```
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
    csp: true
- chrome
- $dart2js:
    csp: true
```

and remove content_security_policy from your manifest.json

this should works

Comment: Please add some content from the link.